# How to use my own NLU module completely with Rasa Core?

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core

If my own NLU service can provide NLU structure like the following:

```
{
  "intent": "search_restaurant",
  "entities": {
    "cuisine" : "Mexican",
    "location" : "center"
  }
}
```

And I only want to use Rasa-core with the output as above. In such a case, I won't have nlu_config, and I don't need to train any NLU at all (done externally). Can you please give some ideas on how to go about this in Rasa-core?

Answer (score 0):

You could connect your own NLU server as it is described [here](https://legacy-docs.rasa.com/docs/core/server/#). 
Create a file `endpoints.yml` with some content like:

```
nlu:
    url: "http://<your nlu host>:<port of your nlu"
    token: <token>  # [optional]
    token_name: <name of the token> # [optional] (default: token)
```

Then run rasa core with the endpoints specified

```
python -m rasa_core.run -d models/current/dialogue \
    -u <project_name>/<model_name> \
    --endpoints endpoints.yml
```

Just make sure that your server has to the correct response format.